# from the age of 9 or 10 via puberty to solidary growing up (what's the meaning of 'solidary'?)

Tags: word-meaning

> Morals change over time and across generations. Generational conflicts are therefore precisely
> due to evolution. What today’s generations in many societies regard as opportune was
> often unacceptable in previous generations. Children are socialized (and thus learn what is
> good or bad, what is right or wrong), especially through their parents, in the family and at
> school. By means of explicit rules and prohibitions as well as implicitly through behavior,
> children are provoked to behave in a way that is considered desirable. Nevertheless, children in their developmental phases (e.g., from the age of 9 or 10 via puberty to **solidary** growing up) challenge the previous value system.The conflicts at generation transitions lead in the long run to adjustments of the moral conceptions. This is to be understood as a clear indication of the social evolution and saves chances of the advancement as well as risks (of the “moral decline”).

(from: AI for the Good: Artificial Intelligence and Ethics-Stefan H. Vieweg · 2021)

Comment: The dictionary (collins) has "marked by unity of interests, responsibilities , etc" (in some theories of child development, becoming solidary is part of the last stages in the development towards adulthood) That said, it is extremely rare except in some specific contexts of education theory.

Comment: It's a *very* rare word (which you could look up). It means becoming sociable / socialized, sharing common interests (in *solidarity*) with your peer group (other teenagers). But I didn't know that myself until I just looked it up.